# Porting WebExtension from Chrome to Edge: dead ico and empty devtools

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, firefox-addon-webextensions

[image: x]]

The same codebase works in Google Chrome, Opera and Firefox. Also, for `popup.js` and `eventPage.js` I added in the first line:

```
window.chrome = window.chrome || window.browser;
```

Where can be a problem? What can I do for fixing my webextension for Edge?

Comment: Please attach the code you used for this addon so we can take a look. Look in the browser console for errors.

Comment: Browser console of the current page?

Comment: Console of the current page might help, yes. Try to strip everything out of the extension to see whether you get it working with less features to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

I have Windows inside VirtualBox and I used shared folder for accessing code of the extension inside VM. I see `popup` after **copying** the code from this shared folder to the local one.

But still without devtools.